# Is this code open to SQL Injection?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, code-injection, mysql-real-escape-string

Can someone tell me if this code is open to SQL Injection and why:

```
$x = $_REQUEST['id'];
$x = mysql_real_escape_string($x);
$del = "DELETE FROM Y WHERE id = ".$x;
mysql_query($del);
```

Comment: Basic rule: if you're **concatenating together** your SQL statement - you're **always** in danger of SQL injection. And **YES** this code of yours is in danger of SQL injection

Comment: @RickHoving You are either trolling or being really unobservant.

Comment: to solve the confusion about `mysql_real_escape_string` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string so yes, it is still unsafe

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

It is; consider `x` being `id`, which leads to a query of

```
DELETE FROM Y WHERE id = id
```

deleting all the rows from the table.

Answer (score 0):

**It is** because you dont quote the x.

You can also use something simple like:

```
sprintf("DELETE FROM Y WHERE id = %u", $x);
```

Answer (score -6):

It shouldn't be as you use mysql_real_escape_string() to escape it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string

Comment: This answer is so bad I want to downvote it more than once.